# How to handle simultaneous modifications to a mysql database from a client application

Tags: c#, mysql, database, winforms, crud

I have a windows forms desktop application that connects to an online mysql database. The application has multiple users who can modify the records in the database. At any given point two or more users can be writing to the database at the same time. Now, I have no idea how to handle this case, there could be as many as 10 or more users performing CRUD on the database simultaneously. I would be grateful, if someone could enlighten on how I should go about this thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this using transaction feature of MySql. Please share your code to eloborate. You can also implement Optimistic locking to have integrity of data